# How to retrieve lookup field value in Pnp Core in c#

Tags: lookup-column, pnp

I am using the Pnp Core library 1.5.0 (https://github.com/pnp/pnpcore) trying to read a lookup value in a sharepoint list.

```
var listNameBookings = "Bookings";
var itemsBookings = await pnpContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitleAsync(listnameBookings, p => p.Title,
                                                 p => p.Fields.QueryProperties(p => p.InternalName,
                                                                               p => p.FieldTypeKind,
                                                                               p => p.TypeAsString,
                                                                               p => p.Title));

var dict = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
foreach(var d in itemsBookings.Items)
{
  var Who = (string)d["Who"];
  var When = (DateTime)d["When"];
  var Where = ((IFieldLookupValue)d["Where"]).LookupValue; // ERROR
  dict[Where] = true;
}
```

But I get an error when the execution reaches the lookup line:

**'((IFieldLookupValue)d["Where"]).LookupValue' threw an exception of type 'PnP.Core.ClientException'**

In details
**Property LookupValue was not yet loaded**

Someone knows how to read it?

Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

- For LookUp Field - use below syntax to access the value

```
 int value = (addedItem["MyField"] as IFieldLookupValue).LookupId;
 string value = (addedItem["MyField"] as IFieldLookupValue).LookupValue;
```

- For Multi lookup fields - use below syntax to access the value

```
 addedItem["MyField"] as IFieldValueCollection).Values

  // Iteration 
  foreach(IFieldLookupValue lookup in (addedItem["MyField"] as IFieldValueCollection).Values)
    {
        // Get the stored lookup id value
        int lookupId = lookup.LookupId; 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks you but it does not work: "Property LookupValue was not yet loaded"

Comment: I assume there is a loading that need to be done to use LookupValue or to get the actual value LookupId refers to?